# How can start multiple tmux autoscript?

Tags: tmux, session

This is in my TmuxHome.sh Script with I can       start One Only Tmux Session:

```
# tmux Start Script Need To Work!!
if which tmux >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    #if not inside a tmux session, and if no session is started, start a new session
    test -z "$TMUX" && (tmux attach || tmux new-session)
fi
```

okay now i want to example TmuxHome.sh use default .tmux.conf and TmuxWork.sh use tmux-work.conf both enable and run separate sessions. how to go about doing this without problems?
Maybe Next TmuxTty.sh or TmuxDev.sh etc...

fine on arch wiki site:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux
it differences now then what it was before

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the appropriate arguments to the two `tmux` calls:

- Pass `tmux` the custom config file using the `-f` argument to `tmux` itself.
- For `new-session`, you should pass the session name using the `-s` argument.
- For `attach`, you pass the session name through `-t` ("t" for "target").

Putting it all together:

```
# TmuxWork.sh
if which tmux >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    #if not inside a tmux session, and if no session is started, start a new session
    test -z "$TMUX" && (
        tmux -f ~/.tmux-work.conf attach -t work ||
        tmux -f ~/.tmux-work.conf new-session -s work
    )
fi
```

(You probably only need to pass the config file to `new-session`, since in most cases it doesn't matter for other commands such as `attach` or commands that run inside the session.)

You can extend this script to actually *switch* to session "work" if you execute it from inside session "home" or another session, by using the `switch-client` command:

```
if test -n "$TMUX" ; then
    tmux switch-client -t work
else
    tmux attach -t work ||
    tmux -f ~/.tmux-work.conf new-session -s work
fi
```

With some scripting, you might be able to store the session name ("work" in this example) and the custom config file name in shell variables and reuse this snippet to have custom scripts for the many sessions you would like to manage.

Comment: # TmuxWork.sh: does not work if TmuxHome.sh are running..
# TmuxHome.sh: does not work if TmuxWork are running..
# TmuxSwitch.sh: only work if TmuxWork are already running..